# Issue using CMS and CD urls in same browser

Tags: experience-editor, content-delivery

I have a CMS environment `cms.<domain>` and a CD environment `www.<domain>`
All works fine when not logged into Sitecore, however when I am logged in to Sitecore on the CMS environment, then try load a page on the CD environment, it crashes with the following:

> 6688 10:55:22 ERROR Application error.    Exception:
>   System.Web.HttpException  Message: The file
>   '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/LoadingIndicator.ascx'
>   does not exist.   Source: System.Web
>        at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
>        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)
>        at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>        at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>        at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Utils.WebUtility.RenderLoadingIndicator(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)
>        at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonWebControl.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)
>        at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.RenderAsText()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.SpeakRibbon.RenderPageEditorSpeakExtender.Render(TextWriter
>   writer)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPageExtendersProcessor.Process(RenderPageExtendersArgs
>   args)
>        at (Object , Object[] )
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.GetExtendersHtml()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.get_ExtendersHtml()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs
>   args)
>        at (Object , Object[] )
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> 6688 10:56:23 INFO  Cache created: 'IsUserInRoleCache' (max size:
>   unrestricted)     6688 10:56:23 INFO  Trying to load XML configuration
>   /App_Config/Security/GlobalRoles.config   6688 10:56:24 INFO  AUDIT
>   (sitecore\Anonymous): Logout  6688 10:56:24 WARN  Protected page
>   accessed with no current user     6688 10:56:24 INFO  AUDIT
>   (sitecore\Anonymous): Logout  6688 10:56:24 WARN  Protected page
>   accessed with no current user     6688 10:56:24 ERROR Application error.
>     Exception: System.Web.HttpException     Message: Cannot redirect after
>   HTTP headers have been sent.  Source: System.Web
>        at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
>        at Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.IsLoggedIn(Boolean returnAfterLogin)
>        at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.PageExtender.RibbonWebControl.DoRender(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)
>        at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.RenderAsText()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.SpeakRibbon.RenderPageEditorSpeakExtender.Render(TextWriter
>   writer)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.RenderPageExtenders.RenderPageExtendersProcessor.Process(RenderPageExtendersArgs
>   args)
>        at (Object , Object[] )
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.GetExtendersHtml()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.PageExtenderResponseFilter.get_ExtendersHtml()
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Request.RequestEnd.AddPageExtenders.Process(RequestEndArgs
>   args)
>        at (Object , Object[] )
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args)
>        at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>        at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> 7520 10:56:24 WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page.
>   Requested url: /sitecore/login?returnUrl=%2F, User:
>   sitecore\Anonymous, Website: login

I assume, this is because, on the CD environment, I have removed the Experience Editor files as per the Sitecore config CD recommendations. Is there any config setting, I am missing for it to not try and load the Experience Editor on the CD environment?

The domain on `httpCookies` and `authentication/forms` are the same value on both CM and CD.

Sitecore 8.2.1

Comment: When you say “environment”- are the two sites in entirely different servers? Different websites within IIS in the same server? How do you have sessions configured?

Comment: Different servers. So I think since on the asp.net cookie the domain is the same, the CD server thinks that we are logged in. The CMS uses in proc session state and the CD uses mssql session state.

Comment: Can you post what are the cookies from your CM call response and what are the cookies in your CD call request?

Comment: They are identical on both. The normal asp.net session and auth cookies, SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE, site#sc_mode, shell#lang=en; sc_expview=0; sc_fv=0.0.0; sc_rte_shuser=..., sitecore_webedit_ribbon=1; sc_last_page_mode_command=webedit:preview, __RequestVerificationToken. Changing the cookie domain isn't an option as the session cookies need to be shared across all subdomains as you can log in as a virtual user.

Comment: You have set the domain attribute on `httpCookies` and/or `authentication/forms` in web.config? Is it the same value on both CM and CD?

Comment: Yes the domain on `httpCookies` and `authentication/forms` are the same value on both CM and CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Original Sitecore 8.2.1 Answer (please use updated Sitecore 8.2.6 answer below)**

I went back over the [CD config guide](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server) and found that I had somehow missed disabling `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Requests.config` and `Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.Speak.Requests.config` which did the trick.

**Sitecore 8.2.6 Answer:**
I ran into this issue again after updating sitecore. They have updated the CD config guide to now include these files on CD so this is no longer a solution.
However simply [disabling edit on CD servers](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/08/07/disable-edit-on-cd-servers/) solves the issue.